# Creating a Login and Register with username and password constraints and saving the data in a file. (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, fstream, string-length

I am a beginner at coding and learning C++. I just wrote a code that asks the user to log in, Register, or exit.
I thought doing it through functions would be easier. While checking for the constraints of the username and password for registration(referred to as "Rusr" and "Rpwd" here) the code I've written to check if lowercase, uppercase, and digits are not working. I tried to do it with character array as well but that didn't work. Would really appreciate some help with this.
Here's my code below for further reference:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool isvalidName(string Rusr)
{
    if(Rusr.length() > 5 && Rusr.length() < 20) // length constraint
        return true;
    else
        cout << "Invalid username" << endl;

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check if digits are present
        {
            if(isdigit(Rusr[i]) == true) 
            return true;
            if(true)
                break;
            else
                cout << "Invalid username";
        }
    }

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check for lowercase
        {
            if(islower(Rusr[i])) {
                return true;
            }
            if(true)
                break;
            else
                cout << "Invalid username";
        }
    }

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check for uppercase
        {
            if(isupper(Rusr[i])) return true;
            if(true)
                break;
            else
                cout << "Invalid username";
        }
    }
}

int isvalidPwd(string Rpwd) {
    {
        if(Rpwd.length() > 8 && Rpwd.length() < 20)
            return true;
        else
            cout << "Invalid password " << endl;
    }

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Rpwd.length(); i++) {
            if(isdigit(Rpwd[i]) == true) return true;
            if(true)
                break;
            else
                cout << "Invalid password";
        }
    }

    {
        if(!((Rpwd.find("@") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("#") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("!") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("$") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("%") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("^") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("&") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("*") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("(") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find(")") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("_") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("+") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("|") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find(">") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("<") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("?") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("/") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find("~") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find(".") == string::npos) ||
             (Rpwd.find(",") == string::npos)))
            return true;

        else
            cout << "should contain special characters" << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Rpwd.length(); i++) {
        if(islower(Rpwd[i])) return true;
        if(true)
            break;
        else
            cout << "should contain lower case";
    }

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Rpwd.length(); i++) {
            if(isupper(Rpwd[i])) return true;
            if(true)
                break;
            else
                cout << "Should contain upper case";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string Lusr, Lpwd, Rusr, Rpwd, name, pwd;

    while(1) {
        cout << "___________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Chose 1 to Register or 2 to Login" << endl;
        cout << "___________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "1.Register" << endl;
        cout << "2.Login" << endl;
        cout << "3.Exit" << endl;
        cout << "___________________________________" << endl;
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 1) // register
        {
            ofstream of("register.txt");
            if(!of.is_open()) {
                cout << "file not exist" << endl;
            }

            do {
                cout << "Username should contain capital,small letters and "
                        "numbers. "
                     << endl;
                cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
                cout << "Enter new username:" << endl;
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, Rusr);
                isvalidName(Rusr);
            } while(isvalidName(Rusr) == true);

            do {
                cout << "Password should contain capital,small letters,special "
                        "characters and numbers. "
                     << endl;
                cout << "_______________________________________" << endl;
                cout << "Enter new passsword:" << endl;
                getline(cin, Rpwd);

                isvalidPwd(Rpwd);
            } while(isvalidPwd(Rpwd) == true);

            of << Rusr;
            of << '\n';
            of << Rpwd;
            of.close();
        }

        else if(choice == 2) {
            ifstream f("register.txt");
            if(!f.is_open()) {
                cout << "file not open" << endl;
            }
            getline(f, name, '\n');
            getline(f, pwd, '\n');

            f.close();

            cout << "Enter username:" << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, Lusr);
            cout << "Enter passsword:" << endl;
            getline(cin, Lpwd);

            if(Lpwd == pwd && Lusr == name) {
                cout << "Welcome " << Lusr << endl;
                ;
                break;
            }

            cout << "Wrong name and  password" << endl;
        }

        else if(choice == 3) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid input!Try again." << endl;
        }
       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that you have a lot of anonymous scope blocks inside your two functions. I suggest placing each such block in a function of its own with a good name that describes what that block is supposed to do. It will not solve the problem, but it will help in debugging. You can then test each function separately etc.

Comment: Reverse your logic, in the functions checking user/password correctness write `if(!someuserrequirement) { return false; } if (!someotherrequirement) { return false; } etc. To check for existence of letter/digit/whatever use [any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with `isalpha` or `isdigit` predicates. To check for existence of special characters, you can use [find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) with your special chars as args.

Comment: Note that the `isvalidName` and `isvalidPwd` return immediately if the length constraint is satisfied. This is the root cause.  If you give a username aaaaaa of 6 letter but without digits.. it's accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both your functions fail to `return` the value you've declared that they should return in all branches, so your program has [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Also, the logic is flawed. Example:

```
bool isvalidName(string Rusr) {
    if(Rusr.length() > 5 && Rusr.length() < 20) // length constraint
        return true;
    else
        cout << "Invalid username`enter code here`" << endl;

    // .. the rest ...
}
```

Here you check that the length is `[6, 19]` characters long - and `return true;` - that's all it takes to get `Rusr` approved. None of the other tests in your function will be executed if the name has an approved length.

Your code is riddled with similar mistakes.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check if digits are present
        {
            if(isdigit(Rusr[i]) == true) return true;
```

The first digit you encounter makes `isvalidName` return `true` - so now you have a name with an invalid length that contains a digit - approved!

Similar issue below. A name with an illegal length, without digits, that contains a lowercase letter is immediately approved:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check for lowercase
        {
            if(islower(Rusr[i])) {
                return true;
```

And finally, if a name with an illegal length, without digits and without lowercase letters contains an uppercase letter, it's approved:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check for uppercase
        {
            if(isupper(Rusr[i])) return true;
```

If none of the above applies - you don't `return` anything (causing *undefined behavior*).

Your second function follows this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, some of your logic is wrong. When you say this

```
if(Rusr.length() > 5 && Rusr.length() < 20) // length constraint
        return true;
    else
        cout << "Invalid username`enter code here`" << endl;
```

Any string that is between 5 and 20 characters will be accepted as a valid username. To fix this, you need to go through all your requirements, then return true. If any of the requirements fail, return false. This makes it so that the only way that the username will be valid is if it has already passed all the requirements.

```
    bool isvalidName(string Rusr)
    {
        if(Rusr.length() < 5 || Rusr.length() > 20) // length constraint
        {
            std::cout << "invalid username length" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check if digits are present
        {
            if(isdigit(Rusr[i]))  // if a digit is present, continue
            {
                break;
            }

            if(i == Rusr.length() - 1) // No digits were found
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check for lowercase
        {
            if(islower(Rusr[i])) {
                break;
            }

            if(i == Rusr.length() - 1) // No lowercase letters were found
            {
                cout << "Invalid username";
                return false;
            }
                
        }
 
        for(int i = 0; i < Rusr.length(); i++) // check for uppercase
        {
            if(isupper(Rusr[i]))
            {
                break;
            }

            if(i == Rusr.length() - 1) // No uppercase letters were found
            {
                cout << "Invalid username";
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This way, the only way you return `true` is if it gets past all the constraints.

For the password, you would want to follow this model and adjust for those constraints.

Some other things to watch out for are the extra braces you have included. Best practice is to not change the scope further in than you need to, so you should avoid the braces in almost every case.